# Why can't I login to my live website? (Drupal7)

Tags: authentication, drupal-7

When I try to log in to my site with admin, the site disappears for me. The whole site. If I clear the cache it restored. So I can't log in.

Why?
Serverproblem?
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons which may cause what you are describing.
When it's like this, log is your best friend. I would suggest you:

**Database log**. Check your empty watchdog table after reloading the broken page. For mysql:

```
DELETE FROM WATCHDOG;
```

Reload the broken page (F5)

```
SELECT * FROM WATCHDOG;
```

**Webserver log**. Check your Webserver log:

```
  sudo tail -f /path/to/your/webserver/error/file.log
```

Reload the broken page (F5)

Read tail output

Comment: this is in my error.log: "[Tue Jun 20 11:31:56.100717 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 20978] [client 66.249.76.109:56943] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/clients/client1/web48/web/.well-known" do you know what is it?

Comment: Debugging log file is a differente issue we can't face here, but you are on the right track. Thanks for accepting my answer above!

Comment: It is possible that when I export a database from phpmyadmin the database get damaged?

Because than I imported an earlier database and now I can log in.

So do you offer me that sometimes I export my database, like a backup?

This is a real danger?